# How to change the native token in Substrate to a custom token?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template, substrate-contracts-node

I want create a custom token in Substrate by the name GGG and I want to use this token for each transaction fee instead of the default Substrate token. Can someone please guide me on how to change the native token in Substrate to my custom token GGG?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is set a custom property for token symbol in the `chainspec.rs` file in the function where you generate the chainspec config. This is typically a function that goes by the name of `development_config` in the substrate node template. Here I've done it:

```rust
let mut props = Properties::new();

props.insert("tokenSymbol".into(), "FYR".into()); 

props.insert("tokenDecimals".into(), "6".into());
```

And then finally attach it to the `ChainSpec` props field :

```rust
Ok(ChainSpec::from_genesis( 
     // Name
     "Development", 
     // ID 
      "dev", 
      ChainType::Development, 
                 move || { 
                         testnet_genesis( 
                                 wasm_binary, 
                                 // Initial PoA authorities 
                                 vec![authority_keys_from_seed("Alice")], 
                                 // Sudo account 
                                 get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"), 
                                 // Pre-funded accounts 
                                 vec![ 
                                         get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"), 
                                         get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"), 
                                         get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"), 
                                         get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"), 
                                 ], 
                                 true, 
                         ) 
                 }, 
                 // Bootnodes 
                 vec![], 
                 // Telemetry 
                 None, 
                 // Protocol ID 
                 None, 
                 None, 
                 // Properties (*Attach your props here*)
                 Some(props), 
                 // Extensions 
                 None, 
         ))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function like this:

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/2d1c1436594b2c397d450e317c35eb16c71105d6/node/service/src/chain_spec/darwinia.rs#L52-L61

Replace the names and the decimals with yours.

One more thing, this could be a `Vec`. So, you can register multiple tokens at one time. As my example shows, our chain has 2 native tokens.

---

Then pass it to your genesis:

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/2d1c1436594b2c397d450e317c35eb16c71105d6/node/service/src/chain_spec/darwinia.rs#L334

Comment: I have to run parachain and do these step on that or i can do them on substrate node ?

Comment: You can write these codes in any Substrate chain's `chain_spec`. Relaychain and parachain, are all Substrate chains.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier if we have 2 native tokens then how do we identify which symbol is assigned to which token e.g if we have different supplies and token specs?