# How to implement token registration, trading and enforce the use of native token for fees in a DEX built with Substrate?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template, substrate-contracts-node

How can I implement token registration, trading, and fee payment with my native token (GGG) in a decentralized exchange (DEX) built with Substrate?

Specifically, I am looking to:

Allow users to add their own tokens to the DEX and enable trading between different tokens.

Use an off-chain worker to periodically send data to the main network and enforce the use of my native token (GGG) as the primary token in the network.

Provide a way for users to upload their smart contracts to create custom tokens on my network. I want to know if I should use the substrate-node-contract or pallet-contract feature to do this.

Ensure that all transactions in the network, including those in DApps, are conducted using my native token (GGG) as the fee payment.

I would appreciate it if you could provide guidance on how to implement these features using the capabilities of Substrate.

Answer (score 2):

To make the fee payment with your own token follow this [step-by-step old response](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3758/2762) where you will have to add the pallet_asset_tx_paymentfro.

I believe about how to create your own native token has been answered [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7132/how-to-change-the-native-token-in-substrate-to-a-custom-token) already.

To have the functionality that allows users to upload WebAssembly smart-contracts in your chain you have to add in your runtime the FRAME pallet [Contracts](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts).

[substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) is an example of a node that has this pallet in its runtime. Another example you can check is [Contracts Rococo](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo) which is a parachain node for smart contracts running in Rococo.

In case you want to allow Solidity Smart contracts, is a bit more tricky but [there are some pallets](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/tree/master/frame) developed that allows it too. You can see an example of a node that has this pallet in its runtime checking the [frontier-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template) and a tutorial about how to use it in the Substrate docs: [Access EVM Accounts](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/access-evm-accounts/).

With the smart contracts feature you can allow users to develop smart contracts and deploy them in your chain implementing a DEX. You can also implement a pallet with the functionality of a DEX that lives in the runtime of your chain.

I share you some resources that I believe can help:

- [substrate-dex pallet:](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-dex) This pallet re-implements Uniswap V1 protocol for decentralized exchange of fungible assets.
- [Dex demo build by substrate](https://github.com/alexxuyang/substrate-dex): This is a full node that acts as a decentralized exchange (DEX) build by substrate.
- [Pablo](https://medium.com/@Picasso_Network/pablo-understanding-the-features-of-our-substrate-native-dex-2ade4bb7b53f): a new-generation decentralized exchange (DEX) that will be the first protocol to launch on Picasso. Check the code of the pallet [here](https://github.com/ComposableFi/composable/tree/main/code/parachain/frame/pablo) and its implementation in Picasso network [here](https://github.com/ComposableFi/composable/blob/main/code/parachain/runtime/picasso/Cargo.toml).